# Node webdriver docs/apis?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am just getting started with webdriver on web test automation.

I checked a lot of places. But I still couldn't find a place where has detailed docs/apis.

Eg,I'm using `yiewd` library on client side. after using `var el = yield driver.elementByCss('.className')`. Because I queried it by class, there could be an array of elements. But how do I find out the array length, and retrieve each by index?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var el = yield driver.elementByCss('.className')
console.log(el.length);
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) { 
    console.log(el[i].getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are docs for JavaScript, more exactly for webdriver, but you can also find more info there.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html